# How to specify bucket path from s3 when there are multiple buckets

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to download a file from s3 bucket that is in multiple buckets. I have realized that '/' cannot be used as a delimiter. I want to know how to get around this issue.

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id = ''
aws_secret_access_key = '' )

s3 = session.resource('s3')

s3.Bucket('bucketName.com/prod/daily-update/2019/08').download_file('test.csv', 'testDownload.csv')

s3.Bucket('bucket-Name/prod/daily-snapshot/2019/08/19').download_file('countries.csv', 'test.csv')
```

I am currently getting a regex error as follows Bucket name must match the regex "`^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$`"

Comment: You should close the quotes correctly. --> `s3.Bucket('bucketName.com/prod/daily-update/2019/08')`

Comment: `/prod/daily-update/2019/08` is a object prefix, not different buckets.

Comment: oh ya sorry about that, did not copy properly, the regex error still presists

Comment: @jordanm ok, so how do I set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the documentation (here)[https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file], I guess you have to run the following code:

Assuming `countries.csv` is the file in the S3 bucket and `test.csv` is the name of the file in which you want to download,

```
s3.Bucket('bucket-Name').download_file('prod/daily-snapshot/2019/08/19/countries.csv', 'test.csv')
```

The argument, `Bucket` requires the name of the bucket and the argument `Key` requires the full path (full key) inside the S3 bucket.

Comment: ah yes this worked, just had to remove the '/' before prod, thanks for the help!